# jenkins mountain lion server

Tags: jenkins, localhost, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to get Jenkins (1.510) running on my MacMini with the latest Mountain-Lion Server OSX installed (10.8.3). On the MacMini-server I've two users: admin, ioscoder and as the ioscoder user I logged-in, opened the jenkins-1.510.pkg and after entering the admin password it installed without problems.
However when the Jenkins-home page should come up, using localhost:8080, I get the following error message in Safari:

```
Safari can't open the page "http://localhost:8080/" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost".
```

After logging in as admin and checking the current running services, being DNS, Open Directory, Websites (PHP- and Python web applications disabled), I also get the same error from above when entering the Jenkins address localhost:8080.
When I switched to the admin-user I saw on the welcome screen a Jenkins-user account, which was created by the jenkins-installer package.

What really puzzles me is that on another iMac, running Mountain Lion (NOT the server version of Mountain Lion), I installed Jenkins in the same way and after the installation finished I immediately got a running Safari which resolved the localhost:8080 to the Jenkins home screen.

Anybody ideas or suggestions why Jenkins is not running on a Mountain Lion Server device?
Google-ing for this specific problem didn't give me any clues yet.

Comment: Does http://localhost:8080/jenkins work ?

Comment: The localhost:8080/jenkins gave me the following:

    Status Code: 404
        Exception: 
        Stacktrace:
        (none)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reading the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins page where an easy installation was mentioned (java -jar jenkins.war) I remembered that java may not have been installed by default on a clean Mountain-Lion Server.
After activating the terminal and typing:

```
server:~ ioscoder$ java -v
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

it asked me if I wanted to install java. After accepting this and performing an installation of java, I was happy to see the 'Dashboard [Jenkins]' page in Safari for the localhost:8080.